# Linq to XML + chaining expressions

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have the following code that's repeated:

```
var ccaNumber = (from r in xDoc.Elements("ResultSet").Elements("DataRow")
         where Convert.ToInt32(r.Element("PaymentPlanNumber").Value) == payPlan.OrderNumber
```

Ideally, I want to create the above as an expression then add my clause to the end of it.

So, I created the expression as follows:

```
Expression currExp = from r in xDoc.Elements("ResultSet").Elements("DataRow")
where Convert.ToInt32(r.Element("PaymentPlanNumber").Value) == payPlan.OrderNumber;
```

I now want to combine them:

```
 var ccaNumber = (currExp  select r.Element("CreditCardAuthorityNumber").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

However I now get the following error:

Invalid expression term ')'

Any suggestions?

ta,

yogi

Comment: Side note: You could use `(int)r.Element("PaymentPlanNumber)` instead of `Convert.ToInt32(r.Element("PaymentPlanNumber").Value)`

Comment: None of your code snippets are valid. Please _please_ show us the _working_ code you started with before you try any changes... it doesn't help anyone if you started with broken or incomplete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing things up here.

What you can do is:

```
var items = from r in xDoc.Elements("ResultSet").Elements("DataRow")
            where Convert.ToInt32(r.Element("PaymentPlanNumber").Value) == payPlan.OrderNumber 
            select r;
```

This declares items as a Enumerable of elements that match your Where-Condition.

And then you can use those defined items like this:

```
var ccaNumber = items.Select(item=>item.Element("CreditCardAuthorityNumber").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

However, this is all utilising lazy evaluation and you need to take care of multiple enumerations here. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/10/04/lazy-evaluation-_2800_and-in-contrast_2c00_-eager-evaluation_2900_.aspx) is a pretty indepth explanaition that is way better than my sh*tty english.

Comment: hiya CSharpie.When I try it as you suggest I get the foloowing error:

Comment: A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Comment: Fixed, pesky copy&paste devils.

Answer (score 0):

When adding to an existing expression, you need to use the lambda syntax, not the Linq syntax:.

Try:

```
 var ccaNumber = (currExp
                  .Select(r=>r.Element("CreditCardAuthorityNumber").Value))
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```